# Trouble understanding why this value is returned

Tags: python, algorithm

I have this code and I am having a lot of trouble understanding why this value is returned and was hoping someone could explain it to me. I am new to loops and indexes so please bear with me.

```
total = 0
while total < 10:
    for i in range(3):
        total += 1
    total *= 2
    print(total)
```

I am having trouble understanding how this only returns values of `6` and `18`.

Comment: Take a pencil and paper and go line by line you will understand the answer

Answer (score 2):

Just see what's happening:

```
total = 0
while total < 10:
    for i in range(3):
        total += 1
```

`total` is now equal to 3.

```
total *= 2
```

`total` is now equal to 6.

```
print(total)
```

It prints "6". `total` is still < 10, so it loops again:

```
while total < 10:
    for i in range(3):
        total += 1
```

`total` is now equal to 6+3=9.

```
total *= 2
```

`total` is now equal to 18.

```
print(total)
```

It prints "18". Now `total` is greater than 10, so your `while` loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
while total < 10:
    for i in range(3):
        total += 1
    total *= 2
    print(total)
```

total=0

intially total value is less then 10 so while loop works then
after this for loop total is

total=total+0

then total=total+1

then total=total+2

So total after for loop is

total=3

then next total statement 
value of total=3*2=6

total after first while loop=6

again it goes to while loop and value is less then 10 and while 
loop works fine

after this for loop total is

total=total+0

then total=total+1

then total=total+2

So total after for loop is 
total=9

then next total statement 
value of total=3*2=18

total after first while loop=18

again it goes to while loop and value is greater  then 10
and while loop does not work and break.